# Functorial properties of the compact open topology.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Let $X,Y,Y'$ be topological spaces and $A\subseteq Y$ a subspace. Every set of continuous maps is equipped with the compact-open topology.

1. Is the canonical map $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\times\mathcal{C}(X,Y')\rightarrow\mathcal{C}(X,Y\times Y')$ a homeomorphism?
2. Does $\mathcal{C}(X,A)$ carry the subspace topology of $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$, i.e. is the map $\mathcal{C}(X,A)\rightarrow \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ given by postcomposing with the inclusion a homeomorphism on its image?

If it changes anything, all spaces can be assumed to be locally compact, Hausdorff and paracompact.

I think the first claim should follow from the fact that $\mathcal{C}(X,\_)$ is a right adjoint of $X\times\_$, so preserves limits, in particular products. (At least if $X$ is locally compact.)  Is the reasoning correct? What about the second question?

Comment: (1) is indeed true by abstract nonsense, at least when the spaces concerned have the stated universal property.

Comment: There is an abstract nonsense argument for (2) in the case where $A$ is a closed subspace of $Y$. But I think it should also be true for non-closed subspaces.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm also interested in the abstract argument you mentioned. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the category of Hausdorff spaces, a morphism is (isomorphic to) the inclusion of a closed subspace if and only if it is a regular monomorphism. Of course, right adjoints preserve regular monomorphisms. For general subspaces, you have to replace "regular monomorphism" with "extremal monomorphism".

Comment: The abstract nonsense proof uses a sequence of isomorphisms which are natural in $W$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Top}(W,C(X,Y×Z))&≅\mathbf{Top}(W×X,Y×Z)\\
&≅\mathbf{Top}(W×X,Y)×\mathbf{Top}(W×X,Z)\\
&≅\mathbf{Top}(W,C(X,Y))×\mathbf{Top}(W,C(X,Z))\\
&≅\mathbf{Top}(W,C(X,Y)×C(X,Z))
\end{align}
This only works if $X$ satisfies the adjuntion, or if we work in a category where the adjuntion holds.

Comment: @StefanHamcke This does not answer the second question, does it?

Comment: As for the second question, let $h:W\to C(X,A)$ be a function such that $i_*h:W\to C(X,Y)$ is a map (where *map* shall always mean continuous). Then by taking adjuncts we have a map $i\bar h:W\times X\to A\to Y$, where $\bar h(w,x)=h(w)(x)$, implying that $\bar h$ is a map by the universal property of the inclusion $i:A\to Y$. Thus $h$ is a map. This shows that $i_*$ is an embedding.

Comment: I guess the first comment I wrote resembles just the usual proof that right adjoints preserve limits. So arguing that $C(X,-)$ is right adjoint is indeed more concise.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, as noted in comments, your argument works.
2. If $K$ is a compact subset of $X$ and $U$ is open subset of $Y$, then the inclusion $A\subset Y$ maps $\{f\in C(X,A):f(K)\subset A\cap U\}$ to the $\{f\in C(X,A):f(K)\subset U\}\bigcap C(X,A)$. So the map $C(X,A)\to C(X,Y)$ identifies elements of subbase of own compact-open topology of $C(X,A)$ with elements of subbase of induced topology on it.